# AirPlay IOS on Flutter

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, airplay

my developers are using flutter to create a radio app for my radio station, and I’m wanting to implement an airplay button which displays similar to this:

[image]

Anyone know how I can achieve a link in flutter to lead to this window?